# JDT eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I want to develop a Java editor eclipse plugin which is slightly different than the normal Java Editor. Is it possible to extend the Normal Java Editor itself? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse you usually do not extend (subclass) an editor (or another feature) but use existing extension points to contribute additional functionality or behaviour.

The eclipse SDKs Help contains a book named 'JDT Plug-In developer guide' with a chapter 'Reference/Extension Points Reference'. There you can find the JDT plugin extension points.

Answer (score 3):

As Andreas said, you don't extend editors.

However, you can reuse the editor configuration and many of the JDT tools.

Here are some things you may want to look at for helpful editor info:

- http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/os-dw-os-ecl-commplgin1.html
  (and parts 2 and 3)
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecjdt/
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_extend_the_JDT%3F